# Connecting by IP avoid DNS lookup

Tags: domain-name-system, ip

Simple question that I tried searching for but haven't found an answer for. As I understand it attempting to connect to say google.com it will go broadcast out for someone who knows where google.com which propagates up the DNS servers until someone knows where that is at which point it returns the ip and the computer uses that to then connect to it.

My question is if I enter an IP directly does that bypass the entire lookup process?

Comment: In theory, sure.

Comment: Sure. But it probably won't solve your problem, whatever it is. And it probably will cause new problems.

Comment: FYI, DNS is not broadcast-based as you describe it, in any way. Your computer has a configuration for what DNS servers to use, and it will always use those, in order depending on the rules of your operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you bypass the entire DNS resolution process in normal configurations, at least for the first HTTP(S) request.

Now, if the website works or not depends (at minimum) on if the server accepts requests without the `Host:` header. You can "fix" this easily too though, just put an entry for the website in your /etc/hosts under linux, on windows there's a similar option.